# Validation Rule: User only can edit the status field during the edition. No other field should be edit

Tags: validation-rule

This is not a duplicated question, but a new one. I created a formula where the user can or should only edit the status field when the status is equal to "Under approval". However, when I change the status to approve or rejected, I can edit the record name and payment name during the edition. How can I prevent user to modify the payment name and account name (lookup) during the record edition? The user should only change the status, not the other fields. The system should not allow the user to save the record, because only the status field can be edit. This is my current formula:

```
AND(ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE( Status__c ), "Under Approval"),AND( NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Unpaid")), NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Paid"))), 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Approved")), 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Rejected")))
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I believe you asked the same question here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/99320/validation-rules-only-the-status-field-can-be-edit? Have you looked at anything since then? How did those solutions provided work?

Comment: THis is not a duplicated question, is a new question. The problem now is, the user can edit 2 fields that cannot be edited while he is updating the status field on the record. This should not happen, the user can't edit these 2 fields during the record editing, the system can't allow the user to do this.

Comment: @BarbaraMoraes - You will not be able to do this via a validation rule alone. I suggest a record type and page layout that makes all possible field read only and WFR to set the record type based on status field. then with the remaining you can check the record type and the other fields for a change and throw the validation error. Otherwise you will have to put every field on the object in the validation rule and that is not maintainable

Comment: Eric, you're right. I gave this solution to the company as a possibility or create a validation rule that will prevent user to edit these 2 fields, no matter what is the record status. Thanks!